# How to use a list comprehension to make the first item in a nested list 0?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-lists

For example if I have a list that is something like:

```
num_list = [
    [1234, 1244123, 453242], 
    [123123, 78421, 76433], 
    [46345, 578542, 47463]
]
```

and I need it to return

```
[
    [0, 1244123, 453242], 
    [0, 78421, 76433], 
    [0, 578542, 47463]
]
```

how would I go about doing this with a list comprehension?

I know how to do it with a nested for loop.
I tried to do something along the lines of:

```
[[x * 0 for x in j[0]] for j in num_list]
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Think about how you would do it for one list, then do that to each list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
num_list = [[0] + i[1:] for i in num_list]
```

output:

```
[[0, 1244123, 453242], [0, 78421, 76433], [0, 578542, 47463]]
```

Comment: but I would probably just use a for loop to change the value of index 0 to 0, not sure why you want to force comprehension.

Comment: A for loop would be a great option, if you can modify the original list. If not, your demonstarted approach works better.

Comment: its for a class and we technically haven't covered loops yet and we arent allowed to use them